# Why do these two date formats differ?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatting

I'm trying to produce just the day number in a WPF text block, without leading zeroes and without extra space padding (which throws off the layout). The first produces the day number with a space, the second produces the entire date. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), 'd' should produce the day (1-31).

```
string.Format("{0:d }", DateTime.Today);
string.Format("{0:d}", DateTime.Today);
```

UPDATE:Adding % is indeed the trick. Appropriate docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx)

> d, %d
>
> The day of the month. Single-digit days do not have a leading zero. The application specifies "%d" if the format pattern is not combined with other format patterns.

Otherwise d is interpreted as:

> d - 'ShortDatePattern'

PS. For messing around with format strings, using [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is invaluable.

Comment: Thanks -- '%' does the trick. Appropriate doc section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers.

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN documentation for "Custom Date and Time Format Strings":

> Any string that is not a standard date
>   and time format string is interpreted
>   as a custom date and time format
>   string.

{0:d} is interpreted as a standard data and time format string.  From "Standard Date and Time Format Strings", the "d" format specifier:

> Represents a custom date and time
>   format string defined by the current
>   ShortDatePattern property.

With the space, {0:d } doesn't match any standard date and time format string, and is interpreted as a custom data and time format string.  From "Custom Date and Time Format Strings", the "d" format specifier:

> Represents the day of the month as a
>   number from 1 through 31.

Answer (score 0):

The `{0:d}` format uses the patterns defined in the [Standard Date and Time Format Strings document of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx). 'd' translates to the short date pattern, 'D' to the long date pattern, and so on and so forth.

The format that you want appears to be the [Custom Date and Time Format Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), which work when there is no matching specified format (e.g., 'd ' including the space) or when you use ToString().

You could use the following code instead:

```
string.Format("{0}", DateTime.Today.ToString("d ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Also includes a redundant space.